# Computar dados seguros randômicamente

Tags: segurança, números-aleatórios

Funções randômicas não são totalmente aleatórias na computação.Gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira segura de gerar um salt,ou qualquer outra string aleatória de forma segura,sem usar hardware externo.

A randomização pode ser obtida sem o uso de hardware externo,por exemplo usando o tempo em que um processo demora para ser feito?Isso não é algo que é intrínseco aos estados quânticos dos materiais do processador?Se não,teoricamente,na menor unidade calculável de tempo por um computador,um processo exatamente igual é sempre calculado na mesma velocidade.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54210/discussion-on-question-by-weslley-c-x-sardinha-computar-dados-seguros-randomicam)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Use hardware externos

Não é possível gerar números totalmente aleatórios **sem hardware externo**.

Como já foi indicado nos comentários da sua resposta, poderia usar ou o [Lavarand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavarand)

Se entrar nos sites que utilizam de serviços Realmente Aleatórios ([Random.org](http://www.random.org/)  ou [HotBits](http://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/)) usam hardware externo para garantir que os números sejam aleatórios:

**Random.org:** usa ruídos em sinais atmosféricos ([referência](ftp://ftp.ngdc.noaa.gov/ionosonde/documentation/CCIR%20-%20Characteristics%20and%20Applications%20of%20Atmospheric%20Radio%20Noise%20Data.PDF)).

**HotBits:** usa o decaimento de particulas radioativas ([referência](http://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/)).

Não consigo ver o por que de usar um hardware externo, como a [API do Random.org](https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/) poderia te trazer problemas de segurança.

## Se insistir em não usá-los:

Como solicitou (exemplos em PHP ou C++), irei postar abaixo a melhor forma de obter números pseudo-aleatórios em PHP:

```js
<?php
mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

echo "<b>mt_rand() com mt_srand()</b><br><br>";


for($i = 0; $i != 5; $i++)
{
    echo mt_rand(0, 100)."<br><br>";
}
?>
```

O `mt_rand()` é muito superior ao `srand()` por usar o [Marsenne Twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html) é provavelmente uma das melhores implementações de números pseudo-aleatórios que existe.

## Se quiser comparar com as outras formas em php:

```js
<?php

echo "<b>rand() sem srand() (semente/alimentação)</b><br><br>";

for($i = 0; $i != 5; $i++)
{

echo rand(0, 100)."<br><br>";

}

srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

echo "<b>rand() com srand()</b><br><br>";


for($i = 0; $i != 5; $i++)
{

echo rand(0, 100)."<br><br>";

}

echo "<b>mt_rand() sem mt_srand()</b><br><br>";

for($i = 0; $i != 5; $i++)
{

echo mt_rand(0, 100)."<br><br>";

}

mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000000);

echo "<b>mt_rand() com mt_srand()</b><br><br>";


for($i = 0; $i != 5; $i++)
{

echo mt_rand(0, 100)."<br><br>";

}

?>
```

## EDITADO:

Achei um tanto suspeita as imagens da resposta aceita e resolvi fazer o teste:

Random.org

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

rand()

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mt_rand()

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código deste teste está no [gist](https://gist.github.com/mansueli/0a4b5ad01e833ff42602) o experimento foi realizado com PHP 5.3
e também pode ser executado online (sem ter que instalar nada [nesse site](http://phptester.net/)).

Comment: Gostei da resposta @Kyllopardium. Deixe-me viajar um pouco: Poderíamos o usar como input uma variável disponível no ambiente, que seja imprevisível, como por exemplo, a terceira parte do IP de client multiplicado pela quarta parte do IP do server ?

Comment: Sim, ao fazer isso [almentará a entropia dos dados](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) o que tornará os seus números mais aleatórios mas mesmo assim sugiro combine com o microtime em algo tipo `mt_srand((double)microtime()*$IP);`

Comment: Sim, exatamente como pensei: ``mt_srand((double)microtime()*($IpClient[2] * $IpServer[3]));``

Comment: PS: sugiro não manter o ip do server na multiplicação caso o mesmo seja estático.

Comment: Que tal ``mt_srand((double)microtime()*($IpClient[rand(0,3)] * $IpServer[rand(0,3)]));`` ?

Comment: Cuidado. Se você usa a hora do servidor para gerar a semente, então o cliente pode descobrir qual é essa semente (se você der uma margem de erro 5 segundo (muito) há apenas 10.000.000 possibilidades de sementes (já que usou microtime), basta testar todas). Utilize uma fonte de hardware, como ler o `/dev/random` do linux, que pode usar o tráfego de rede para randomizar. Imagino que um servidor tenha bastante.

Comment: "Não consigo ver o por que de usar um hardware externo, como a API do Random.org poderia te trazer problemas de segurança." Usar um hardware que você possui ([e confia](http://blog.cr.yp.to/20140205-entropy.html)) é uma coisa, usar um serviço de terceiros para algo que deveria ser confidencial é outra. O próprio Random.org diz na sua FAQ: ["...anyone genuinely concerned with security **should not trust anyone else** (including RANDOM.ORG) to generate their cryptographic keys."](https://www.random.org/faq/#Q2.4) (ênfase minha)

Comment: Todas as vezes que consumimos um serviço de terceiros, que geralmente envolve tráfego por redes de terceiros, existem vários perigos dependendo da implementação, seja sua, seja do terceiro. Quanto mais 'pessoas' estão envolvidas num processo, maior a complexidade para gerenciar a segurança.

Comment: Quando à imagem "suspeita" do `rand`, o artigo citado explica que esse resultado foi obtido somente no Windows, que no Linux não houve padrão semelhante. O que mostra que o gerador de números aleatórios *daquela versão do Windows* era ruim. Não sei se isso se aplica a versões recentes. De todo modo, nada disso "prova" nada, pois pode-se criar resultados que *pareçam* aleatórios, mas que ainda escondam um padrão. A qualidade de um PRNG deve ser testada usando [métodos específicos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests).

Answer (score 16):

Antes de responder diretamente a sua pergunta, eu gostaria de estabelecer alguns paralelos que irão ajudar no entendimento da resposta.

Primeiro, avalie as sequências abaixo e suas fórmulas correspondentes:

```
01010101010101010101010101   f(X) = NOT X
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   f(X) = "A"
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ   f(X) = CHAR(ASCII(X) + 1)
```

Sem muito trabalho, chegamos à conclusão que a previsibilidade (ou definição determinística) dessas sequências é muito alta - ou, inversamente, que a entropia é muito baixa.

Mas o que é entropia? É a medida de caos de um sistema. O termo foi originalmente criado para descrever sistemas termodinâmicos, mas o conceito é também aplicável a outros domínios - dados, por exemplo.

Quando falamos da geração de conteúdo aleatório ou randômico por parte de computadores, estamos falando de fórmulas que geram valores que possuem uma distribuição similar à encontrada em sistema com alta entropia e distribuição uniforme contínua.

Um exemplo de distribuição uniforme contínua de fácil visualização é o ruído branco, onde a distribuição é aparentemente impossível de ser descrita com uma fórmula determinística - mas onde podemos usar estatística para descrever a densidade. Este é um bitmap de ruído branco gerado no Random.org:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para comparação, este é o mapa de bits da função Rand() do PHP como demonstrado pelo desenvolvedor Bo Allen em um post de 2012 no seu blog pessoal intitulado [*Pseudo-random vs. True random*](http://boallen.com/random-numbers.html). Note o quão facilmente você detecta o padrão de geração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Enquanto que na natureza sistemas perdem ordem e ganham entropia, o inverso ocorre em sistemas de dados. Sempre que você 'gera' números aleatórios, você está roubando o sistema de entropia, e inserindo ordem.

Como exemplo, vamos assumir que eu possuo a seguinte sequência aleatória de letras via Random String Generator do random.org:

```
Chave
JPVPUUWWJAZEEUMLXDVT
```

Que utilizo em uma fórmula simples de encriptação, onde eu 'adiciono' a variação em relação à letra A de cada posição quando aplicando à uma letra do meu payload na mesma posição.

```
Payload               Conteúdo encriptado
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA  JPVPUUWWJAZEEUMLXDVT
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB  KQWQVVXXKBAFFVNMYEWU
```

Mas note que, se meu payload for igual ou maior que a chave, eu zerei a entropia do sistema. Assim, assuma que eu concateno minha chave, para o seguinte payload:

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Meu conteúdo encriptado seria:

```
JPVPUUWWJAZEEUMLXDVTJPVPUUWWJAZEEUMLXDVT
^^^                 ^^^
```

Posso assim facilmente detectar a repetição e prever o resto da sequência.

Do ponto de vista de segurança, funções aleatórias seguras são aquelas que periodicamente se recarregam com entropia, com o objetivo de prevenir previsibilidade.

Você pode recarregar entropia de várias maneiras; A melhor fonte de entropia é o mundo real. Alguns exemplos, que podem ser utilizados em conjunto com uma função pseudo-randômica na forma de seeds (sementes):

- Acesse os trending topics do Twitter. Pegue os últimos 128 tweets gerados. Extraia o dia e hora de cada um, converta para um byte array.
- Capture imagens de 2 ou mais webcams públicas ao redor do mundo. Extraia o MD5 de todas. Converta para um byte array.
- Deixe seu gato andar em cima do teclado. Converta os caracteres gerados para um bytearray. (Adicione um hamster ao sistema para maior quantidade de dados. Previna o abandono de escopo do sistema com uma caixa ao redor dos três.)

Cada um desses exemplos fornece tamanho e taxa de amostragens diferentes. Quanto mais dados de origem aleatória você inserir em um sistema híbrido com um gerador pseudo-randômico acoplado, menores são as changes de detecção de padrões.

A resposta, portanto, é **não**: Você precisa importar entropia de um sistema externo.

Fontes:

http://www.random.org/strings/?num=10&len=10&upperalpha=on&unique=on&format=html&rnd=new

http://boallen.com/random-numbers.html

<sub>edit-disclaimer: Adicionada, diretamente no texto, a menção ao post onde o imagem do função `RAND()` foi retirada.</sub>

Comment: Retirei meu voto pra fechar (como duplicada) porque essa resposta fez valer muito a pergunta. :)

Comment: Eu realmente gostei da resposta,esclareceu muitas coisas a mim, abriu uma porta para a solução da pergunta, computadores não possuem um pouco de entropia? Pois seus relógios internos geralmente se dessincronizam. Essa  dessincronia é sinal de uma entropia mesmo que baixa(tendo em vista sua imprevisibilidade) ou de algum efeito desconhecido por mim?

Comment: Funções para geração de aleatoriedade são feitas para serem rápidas. Minha pergunta ignora essa necessidade.

Comment: @WeslleyCXSardinha Você está certo - sim, algumas características entrópicas estão presentes nos computadores modernos. Entretanto, várias sofrem algum tipo de tratamento na camada de hardware, não sendo expostas para nenhum tipo de consumo ou inferência por parte do software. Tempo de processamento, entretanto, é uma inferência possível, como você apontou. O efeito fotoelétrico também. Ainda assim, você está importando entropia de um sistema externo.

Comment: Sim, sistema externo, mas sem hardware externo.Esclareceu minhas duvidas sobre o assunto.

Comment: Boa resposta, só tenho duas coisas a comentar: 1) Seu exemplo de "fórmula simples de encriptação" é uma [cifra de vigénere](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifra_de_Vigen%C3%A8re), totalmente "quebrada" nos dias atuais; creio que você tentou usá-la como um *one-time-pad* (e se foi isso, seu comentário sobre o tamanho da chave ser menor que o da mensagem está totalmente correto), mas acabou fazendo um "two-time-pad" quando combinou tanto com `A*` quanto com `B*`... Na minha opinião sua resposta ficaria melhor sem esse exemplo, ele não acrescenta nada, e o resto da resposta já está ótimo como está.

Comment: 2) Ao contrário do que diz nosso senso comum, [adicionar entropia a um sistema pode **piorar** sua segurança!!!](http://blog.cr.yp.to/20140205-entropy.html) Eu não tenho conhecimento suficiente para opinar sobre o assunto, mas de qualquer forma sugero evitar fontes de entropia que podem estar sob controle de um adversário (dependendo do seu nível de "paranoia", evite coletar entropia da internet, por mais inócuos que pareçam os dados consultados).

Comment: @mgibsonbr Agradeço os comentários - em relação a (1), o foco foi em demonstrar a introdução de entropia, enquanto que a segunda parte demonstra a exaustão de entropia, tornando o sistema perfeitamente previsível. O exemplos dados não devem ser seguidos como recomendações de algoritmo. A necessidade de introdução a partir de um sistema externo ainda é necessária, e sua ressalva em (2) é coerente; os exemplos assumem que entropia está sendo guarantida para o sistema mencionado.

Answer (score 11):

Dados aleatórios só podem ser obtidos a partir de procesoss aleatórios. Fisicamente, apenas processos quanticos são realmente aleatórios e por isto existem dispositivos externos que geram dados aleatórios: contadores geiger, junções PN polarizadas reversamente etc.

Sem usar um equipamento externo, você pode:

- obter dados de sites que geram números aleatórios: se você confiar nestas fontes e no processo que elas utilizam, pode obter estes dados externamente
- utilizar os números pseudo-aleatórios gerados em seu próprio computador: as melhores fontes são as do seu sistema operacional, pois devem ter sido construídos seguindo as melhores práticas vigentes à época de sua construção.
- em geral, se você utilizar as funções/métodos/o que quer que seja da sua linguagem de programação, ele buscará as do sistema operacional. E serão as melhores fontes disponíveis para você.
- fazer sua própria fonte: em geral, é muito fácil cometer algum engano e acabar gerando números menos aleatórios dos que os obtidos pelo próprio sistema operacional. A não ser que você desconfie/saiba que os números do seu SO não são confiáveis, o que no caso significa que seus problemas são piores do que só confiar ou não nos números que ele fornecer.

[Editada por alteração da pergunta]

> A randomização pode ser obtida sem o uso de hardware externo,por exemplo usando o tempo em que um processo demora para ser feito?

Sim, o tempo que um processo demora pode sofrer alterações, já que a frequência de processamento de um processador pode variar com temperatura, tensão etc. Mas esta variação pode ser extremamente pequena, talvez imperceptível. Poderia ser verificada com o uso de um relógio? Sim, poderia, com um relógio extremamente preciso, ex., um relógio atômico ou GPS. Mas isto não é "interno" a um computador. Um programa, rodando dentro de um computador, não sabe quanto tempo levou para executar, sem utilizar um relógio de precisão externo.

> Isso não é algo que é intrínseco aos estados quânticos dos materiais do processador? Se não, teoricamente, na menor unidade calculável de tempo por um computador, um processo exatamente igual é sempre calculado na mesma velocidade.

Exatamente. Se você tem um processador rodando a 3.2GHz e cada instrução levar um ciclo para ser executado, significa que cada instrução será executada em 0,3125 nanosegundos para executar. Se o seu processador estiver rodando a 3.199GHz, cada instrução levará 0,3126 nanosegundos. Não é simples possuir um relógio que consiga detectar esta diferença de tempo.