# Previsibilidade algorítmica na geração de números aleatórios

Tags: números-aleatórios

> Ao terminar de escrever [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191784) pergunta, percebi que ela estava muito ampla. Por isso resolvi quebrá-la em tópicos.

Existe uma maneira sucinta de se observar a previsibilidade de um sistema aleatório?

Seria possível, considerando os elementos, tamanho de chave, *noise*, algoritmos X,Y,Z, determinar se um sistema é *"mais aleatório"* do que outro?

Caso não exista *forma simples* de fazê-lo, como seria possível analisar esse aspecto de um sistema?

Comment: Pode especificar melhor o seu problema e o que pretende com isso por favor? Pode existir alguns metodos de "prever" números aleatórios mas é necessário alguns dados sobre o sistema em que estes números estão a ser lançados